# Is there any tool to monitor kannel?

Tags: rubygems, smpp, kannel

Is there any tool to monitor kannel?

1- smsc online /offline

2- queued up , dlr queued up

3- some time kannel got stuck and will not accept any message

Answer (score 1):

If Kannel is installed properly then you will find the 
http:// yourSystemIP : KannelPort / status.xml (please remove spaces)
Parse the file and you can get following from it

```
Kannel Uptime
Sqlbox Uptime
Gateway Uptime
Smsbox Uptime
```

and some other informations

Answer (score 0):

You should try following url
http://www.ddj.co.za/kannel-web-configuration-tool
Current features:

```
Update Kannel configuration files
View Kannel status
Stop/start SMSC’s
```

Comment: i created a ruby gem for monitor all kannel and smsc status take look at this https://rubygems.org/gems/kannel_monitor